# Most elegant way to solve a complex array join and analysis?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm not trying to be purposefully vague in the title, I apologize.  Just couldn't figure out a good and succinct way to solve this problem.

I'm building an application that shows, for a set of individuals, where they are within a rolling 28 days.  Visually (I dunno that this matters), we're basically talking about a table with people down the left-most column, that 28 days across the top, and whereabouts in the table cells.

The source data is built out of two lists (in SharePoint).  In one, they log their "default" location.  In another, they indicate when and where they're going to be traveling. In either case, I get an array of objects back that look like this:

From the Whereabouts list:

```
[
    {Date:'2017-05-25T00:00:00Z',EventLength:'Full Day',TeamMem:'Person McPerson',Title:'Public Holiday'},
    //Lots more.
]
```

From the Default Locations list:

```
[
   {TeamMem:'Person McPerson',Location:'Main Office'}
]
```

I need to figure out how to merge all that together so that, for each individual, I've got an array of objects that gives the person's location on any day between today and today+28 days.  Fun side note, the items they plug into the Whereabouts list can be a full day or a half day (PM or AM).  So I also need to account for half days in this merge.

[This is how I've solved it.](https://jsfiddle.net/uxbvtugp/)

TL;DR, I make an array of the 28 days, use underscore's _.difference() function to find the days, per team member, where there is no whereabouts entry, add an item back to the whereabouts array for each of those dates indicating the default location, then do a thing I can barely follow that I did a year ago to handle the half day items.

It works, but I know it's probably not the most elegant way to handle this.  Anyone have any ideas?

**Edit for clarity**

Ultimately, I need to have 28 items in an array per person, one for each day that I'm tracking whereabouts for.  Within a 28 day period, between Today and Today+28 Days, I should have some whereabouts information and some default locations, depending on what the team member has actually logged into the system.

**More Edits**

I could be persuaded against this, but I'm thinking the final array needs to look something like this:

```
[
    Person1 McPerson:[//Array of 28 events, either their whereabouts or defaults.],
    Person2 McPerson:[//Array of 28 events, either their whereabouts or defaults.],
    Person3 McPerson:[//Array of 28 events, either their whereabouts or default locations.],
    //Etc, for however many people.
]
```

**Edit with additional examples**

Hopefully these clarify things a bit:

- [Whereabouts list return example](https://jsfiddle.net/n8pqa7Ly/)
- [Defaults list return example](https://jsfiddle.net/c7pz3Lc5/)
- [Final markup](https://jsfiddle.net/6px624s7/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand what you want with the dates. It could help if you have:

- Bigger arrays to start, with both items that get filtered out and items that stay
- What the resulting array should look like

Here is my answer so far:

```
// POLYFILL FOR Array.prototype.find 

// https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.find
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'find', {
    value: function(predicate) {
     // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
      if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
      }

      var o = Object(this);

      // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
      var len = o.length >>> 0;

      // 3. If IsCallable(predicate) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
      if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
      }

      // 4. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
      var thisArg = arguments[1];

      // 5. Let k be 0.
      var k = 0;

      // 6. Repeat, while k < len
      while (k < len) {
        // a. Let Pk be ! ToString(k).
        // b. Let kValue be ? Get(O, Pk).
        // c. Let testResult be ToBoolean(? Call(predicate, T, « kValue, k, O »)).
        // d. If testResult is true, return kValue.
        var kValue = o[k];
        if (predicate.call(thisArg, kValue, k, o)) {
          return kValue;
        }
        // e. Increase k by 1.
        k++;
      }

      // 7. Return undefined.
      return undefined;
    }
  });
}

// END OF POLYFILL



var whereabouts = [
  {Date:'2017-05-25T00:00:00Z',EventLength:'Full Day',TeamMem:'Person McPerson',Title:'Public Holiday'},
];

var defaultLocations = [
  {TeamMem:'Person McPerson',Location:'Main Office'}
];


var result = whereabouts
  .filter(function(el) { return new Date(el.Date) > new Date() && new Date(el.Date) < new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 28))})
  .map(function(el, i) {
    el.Location = defaultLocations
      .find(function(lo) { return lo.TeamMem === el.TeamMem; })
      .Location;
    return el;
  });

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hey, sorry if that wasn't clear.  I may not need the dates.  I was using the dates to determine whether or not I had a whereabouts for that day.

Comment: I see. I changed the code slightly cause I was assuming that the array are of same size and corresponding indices, which is not necessarily true. Please let me know if this works for you or not.

Comment: Hmm.  I can't use .find() on a regular array.  I switched that out for .filter (since we're just filtering defaults by the current team member), but that's still only returning the original 10 or so whereabouts from the whereabouts list.

Comment: It would really help if you provide more info: a more complete array of the whereabouts list, a more complete array of the default locations list, and an example of the desired result

Comment: By the way, why not use an Array.prototype.find polyfill? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example#Polyfill

Comment: Because I'm a hacky coder with maybe 2 years of experience, tops?  I'll see if I can't provide a more complete example of the whereabouts and defaults list.  There's a _lot_ of data there. Edit: even with the polyfill, it's still only spitting out the original set of whereabouts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144952/discussion-between-sven-ten-haaf-and-chrispeditor).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't.  The chat app is blocked by my company's proxy.  I appreciate all your attention here, and I don't want to take up any more of your time.